# How to download an external SQLite database in a phonegap application?

Tags: database, sqlite, mobile, cordova

I have a SQLite database hosted in a server, e.g. http://www.webserver.com/database.db

I need to download this database into my phonegap/cordova application, in order to read its data offline.

Practically, I need to "clone" my external database into an internal one.

Please, could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Old question, but here is a reference on how to do it https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/223

Comment: If the sqlite database is pre-populated, I found the best solution to be LiteHelpers  (Chris Brody)  CORDOVA-SQLITE-EXT,
 which is an off-shoot of the one mentioned above by Moinul Hossain.
  (https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext)

Comment: You might find my answer posted here helpful:     http://stackoverflow.com/a/43525272/4647582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. First, PhoneGap does not supporting download a SQLite db file and then connect to it. I believe it is *possible* if I use a native plugin, but out of the box, I can't do it that way.

Solution: download raw data via XHR, i. e. JSON data, and then do imports.